# Is it possible to limit the depth of a recursive directory listing in S3 bucket?

Tags: recursion, amazon-s3, ls

I used the following command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mydir --recursive > bigfile
```

The resulting file was too huge (9.5MB) to conveniently work with, since I need to eyeball the info I'm looking for.

All I really need is the information three levels down. Is it possible to adjust this command so that I only recurse down N number of levels instead of all the way down every directory? I don't see any thing like `-maxdepth`for S3 CLI ls commands

**Update:** Here is the command I ended up using to get the info I needed, though I'm not satisfied with it. It still gave me 77000 results when I only wanted the 40 or so unique values, but it was short enough to port into excel and whittle down with text-to-columns and remove duplicates.

```
 aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mydir --human-readable --summarize --recursive | egrep '*_keytext_*' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f5 >smallerfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not have the concept of 'levels'. It is a flat storage system, with the path being part of the object name (Key). Some API calls, however, support the ability to specify a `Prefix`, which can operate like looking in a particular directory.

An alternative to using `aws s3 ls` is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file listing the contents of a bucket.

Answer (score 6):

While the accepted answer is strictly true, it's still very useful to have this feature, as evidenced by the bug report on the aws-cli (https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2683).

I worked around this with a `bash` script and an `awk` script.  The bash scripts gets a single level, the `awk` script parses the output and will recursively call the `bash` script to get the next level.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Save as ./s3-tree.sh
bucket=$1; max_depth=$2; path=${3:-}; depth=${4:-1};
[ $depth -gt $max_depth ] || \
  aws s3 ls "s3://$bucket/$path" | \
  awk -v bucket="$bucket" -v path="$path" -v depth="$depth" -v max_depth="$max_depth" -f s3-tree.awk
```

```
#!/bin/awk
# Save as: ./s3-tree.awk
BEGIN  { FIELDWIDTHS = "10 1 8 1 10 1 600" }
$5 == 0 { next } # Ignore zero-size files
{ print $1 " " $3 " " $5 " " path $7 }
$5 == "       PRE" && depth <= max_depth { system("./s3-tree.sh " bucket " " max_depth " " path $7 " " depth+1); next }
```

invoke as:

```
./s3-tree.sh <my-bucket-name> <max-depth> [<starting-path>]
```

Share and enjoy!

Comment: it didn't work for me (MacOS), it shows results like this: `PRE   <my-prefix>` and that's it

Comment: @KhaledAbuShqear - MacOS has some quite different versions of Posix's tools. You could try `brew` installing GNU `awk` and change `awk` to `gawk`.  That's just a very quick guess, but worth isolating first.  Also possible that a change in the tooling has resulted in a different output format: worth checking if the `FIELDWIDTHS` took correct.

Comment: Also not working for me on RHEL (Linux). `awk --version` is GNU Awk 4.0.2. Any idea how we could figure out the appropriate `FIELDWIDTHS`?

Comment: @Wassadamo Just run the `aws s3 ls` on one of the levels of the bucket and hopefully the FIELDWIDTHS can be determained from that.  This could be a change in the aws cli output, or it may be that it's trying to utilises full-screen-widths.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't a pure shell+awscli workaround, the Python package `s3fs` has a reasonably fast recursive globbing function, and s3fs is pretty mature

for example

```
# pip install s3fs
import s3fs
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

s3.glob(f'{BUCKET}/*/*findme*')
# much slower of course
s3.glob(f'{BUCKET}/**/*findme*')

# returns
'''
['BUCKET/checkpoints/findme',
 'BUCKET/checkpoints/temp_findme_other',
 'BUCKET/tables/findme',
 'BUCKET/tables/temp_findme_other']
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `aws cp` provides `--include`, `--exclude`, and `--dryrun` flags, we can make use of those to achieve `ls` with a depth.

For example, for a recursive `ls` for `depth=1`:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive --exclude '*/*' s3://bucket/folder . --dryrun | awk '{print $3}'
```

For `depth=2`:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive --exclude '*/*/*' s3://bucket/folder . --dryrun | awk '{print $3}'
```

List only `.py` files for `depth=2`:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive --exclude '*' --include '*.py' --exclude '*/*/*' s3://bucket/folder . --dryrun | awk '{print $3}'
```

Note that the order of `--exclude` and `--include` flags matter.